# Editable, clickable image

Tags: sharepoint-designer, image-display

I have a question concerning the possibility to upload an editable picture into  SharePoint.

For example - there should be a picture (with 7 phases and each in separate square), but the buttons should be clickable. This "clickable" mode is needed to for getting the Users into more detailed description of a phase.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box this is not possible.

You can store the pictures in a SharePoint picture library. And then use JavaScript to drill down the picture.

You can put the JavaScript inside a Content Editor Webpart (in case of 2010) or Script Editor Webpart (in case of 2013).

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with a embedded Microsoft Visio Drawing where you can create links on specific areas on a drawing to other URL's or link to other Documents. You can embed a Visio drawing in a SharePoint site.

However you need to create a [Visio Graphics Service service application](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee524058.aspx)

[Add a hyperlink Visio](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/273814)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list or a piece of reusable content, which has the columns image and link- with the image being a publishing image and the link being...a link.

Then use a content query web part to pull the data out. You can also export the web part and and import it, essentially creating your own custom web part.

Or you could hard code it as HTML.

Either way, there's no quick win.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map tag of HTML. The map tag is used to define a client-side image-map. An image-map is an image with clickable areas.

Here is more information on [map tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) and how it can be used.